# select rows where today is between dates held in table

Tags: sqlite, date

using sqlite (although I would also like to do it with SQLServer at a later date)

I have a table which contains the start date of an exchange rate. I want to select row where a the start date is between to dates held in a column in the table

eg

```
StartDate   ISO  Rate  
2020/11/24  EUR  1.12  
2020/11/26  EUR  1.15
```

so if today is 2020/11/24 or 2020/11/25 the rate is 1.12, if today is 2020/11/26 or later the rate is 1.15

Comment: Please update your answer with which database management system you're using so that you can receive more contextual appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your post with which database system you are using, I will update my answer on how to query in that system accordingly.

Here's how you would accomplish it with T-SQL syntax (on a Microsoft SQL Server instance):

```
WITH CTE_Rates_OrderedByStartDate_Desc AS -- CTE to sort the RatesTable by date
(
    SELECT StartDate, ISO, Rate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS SortId -- Sorting by latest StartDate to oldest
    FROM RatesTable
    WHERE StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) -- Filter out dates in the future, using built in GetDate() function casted to just a Date
)

SELECT StartDate, ISO, Rate
FROM CTE_Rates_OrderedByStartDate_Desc 
WHERE SortId = 1 -- Give us the max record (latest StartDate) that is before or on today
```

Please see the query comments for explanation on what each piece of the query does.